# Finding Bitrate of video file

Tags: c++, video, bitrate

How can we find bitrate of a video file in c++? Can we do this by file handling?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Install  [FFMEPG](http://ffmpeg.org/) it will give you all the information related to the video

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i filename.flv
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! but is there anyway to do it using pure C++. Just Asking! BTW thanks

Comment: Well you will need to understand how so many video file formats work, basically it will be a BYTE level inspection of data and from there . you will decide what the bit rate would be. Doable but lengthy. Here is a link to Avi header formate. Read down to samples per second part and you will understand what I mean http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/programming/avi/avi.html

Comment: Thats preety difficult cux I haven't learnt Win32 Api. I'll see may be i'll use ffmepg.

Comment: You can use ffmpeg C library. http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.2/group__libavc.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement such yourself you need to be able to read the video container format (Quicktime, ASF, AVI, Matroska etc) and try to find the bitrate from the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffprobe from the ffmpeg project to get the information about your video files and get a nice JSON ouput.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802769/1006863) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Bitrate can be accessed from an AVFormatContext formed from an open video file.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650183) for an example of how to open the format context and access using c++.

You might also take a look at `get_bit_rate(...)` [from avcodec.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avcodec_8c_source.html#l00085), which returns the correct bitrate, even when the codec_type for the format context is an audio file.